# Setting layout dimensions and clipping all insides controls

Tags: android, android-layout

Is it possible to forcefully set dimensions of a layout and **clip** its content?

For example, see following layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Test" />
</FrameLayout>
```

In this layout, `FrameLayout` size will be equal to `Button`. Now assume that I want to set this layout's dimension to 50dp width and height, **clipping** all controls (here button) in that size, so that total size of layout will be 50dpx50dp. Is it possible to do so?

I thought setting width, height, and `android:clipChildern="true"` for layout should do the trick, but it seems that it does not work. or maybe I'm using it incorrectly.

Comment: Try using match_parent for Button and then set the desired height and width for the FrameLayout

Comment: @Basu it is not feasible. This is a small layout, but assume that you have a big layout with several control, each in its correct position and size. I like to practically force size outer layout without changing anythind inside. That's why I said "**clip children**".

Comment: So clipChildren works dynamically. Example: if the button has an animation added to it that grows its size to say 500dp and then after a second, brings it back to its normal state so if you have yes in clipChildren, it won't cross the FrameLayout's boundary.